# How to resolve ERROR [42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC-Treiber] [DB2 fur i5/OS]SQL0113 - Name

Tags: vb.net, db2, ibm-midrange

I work with VB.NET (Windows Forms) and database in AS400 iSeries. I wont to make an Update in one table. I have this code:

```
    query.Append("Update CLAIMSTATE ")
    query.Append("SET CST_CODE = @cst_code, ")
    query.Append("CST_LABEL = @cst_label, ")
    query.Append("CST_POINTS = @cst_points ")
    query.Append("WHERE CST_ID = @cst_id ")

    Dim command As New OdbcCommand(query.ToString(), con)   

    command.Parameters.Add("@cst_id", OdbcType.BigInt).Value = row.Cells(0).Value
    command.Parameters.Add("@cst_code", OdbcType.Char).Value = row.Cells(1).Value & ""
    command.Parameters.Add("@cst_label", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = row.Cells(2).Value & ""
    command.Parameters.Add("@cst_points", OdbcType.Decimal).Value = row.Cells(3).Value
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

In this case I obtain this error:
ERROR [42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC-Treiber][DB2 fur i5/OS]SQL0113 - Name @CST_CODE not allowed.

Can anybody help me?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`OdbcCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.aspx) doesn't support named parameters.

```
Dim command As OdbcCommand = con.CreateCommand()
command.CommandText = "UPDATE CLAIMSTATE " & _
    "SET CST_CODE = ?, CST_LABEL = ?, CST_POINTS = ? WHERE CST_ID = ?"
command.Parameters.Add("@cst_code", OdbcType.Char).Value = row.Cells(1).Value & ""
command.Parameters.Add("@cst_label", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = row.Cells(2).Value & ""
command.Parameters.Add("@cst_points", OdbcType.Decimal).Value = row.Cells(3).Value
command.Parameters.Add("@cst_id", OdbcType.BigInt).Value = row.Cells(0).Value
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```